# Nth child inheriting the transform and the transition from other childs

Tags: html, css

I have a li with nth child design which animate on hover, 
so i'm diving my li effect based on the multiple of numbers

```
  <ul id="">
    <li>    
      <p></p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
li:nth-child(n+1){transform}
li:nth-child(n+1):hover {}
li:nth-child(n+2) { style but do not transform}
li:nth-child(n+2):hover {}
li:nth-child(n+3) {transform}
li:nth-child(n+3):hover {}
```

the thing is my second n+2 child is inheriting the transform and the transition from my n+1 css even though it should not

and if i removed li:nth-child(n+2) from my css i can still see that the second li is using my first li
how to make my n+2 doesn't inherit the css from n+1

Comment: Try using nth-child with odd/even rules like `p:nth-child(odd) {
    /*css rule*/
}`. Same for even.

Comment: but i need to apply 3 repetitive styles different styles imagine a for loop     {1 2 3}  if i'm using odd even then i can apply 2 repetitive style {1,2} which is not what i am doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the factor 3 according to you repetition pattern and add the offset (1, 2 or 3):

```
/* 1st, 4th, 7th, … item */
li:nth-child(3n+1){…}

/* 2nd, 5th, 8th, … item */
li:nth-child(3n+2){…}

/* 3rd, 6th, 9th, … item */
li:nth-child(3n+3){…}
```

There are [some good examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Answer (score 0):

That is because `n+1` targets everything (*when n=0 target 1, when n=1 target 2, when n=2 target 3 etc*). (*in general `n+x` means target evertything after `x` including `x`*)

You might want to use `:nth-child(1)` for the first, `:nth-child(2)` second, etc..

The `n` is usually useful when using it as a multiplier.

Comment: but my li is generated dynamically it is not possible